# Intellij Git Error

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm new to using both IntelliJ and Git. I'm working on a Mac, if that matters.

When attempting to use Git in IntelliJ I get two error messages. I've searched for fixes yesterday and today, but nothing I've tried is fixing the issue. I need some help, so I jump out the window.

First, when launching a new project in IntelliJ I get: `"Unregistered VCS root detected."` As far as I can tell, my Git account is set up properly in Preferences. Path to Git Executable is `/usr/local/bin/git`. I have an API token for Github setup and that tests fine. My `gitconfig` and `gitignore` files look good. I set up a global gitignore, but I'm not sure where that is.

Second, after I click "Add Root" or "Configure" in the error above, I click on "Version Control" and see "Default updating . . . " in the first line. Nothing happens and I get the error `Error updating changes java.lang.OutOfMemory: Java heap space during executing git - c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false ls-files --exclude-standard --others -z --`.

Maybe helpful, is that when I open VS Code, I am told that there are too many changes, so Git is running with fewer features. I hoped that the ignore file would help this, but I'm not sure. I'll add a screen shot of VS Code below, just because it shows some of the actual files. Importantly, the staged changes are from a file that I deleted.

At this point, I'd be happy if there is a way to completely reset Git on my system and start from scratch. I don't have anything in Git that I need at this point. I'm just trying to get it setup.

Thanks for your help, in advance.

[VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY4G7.jpg)

Comment: Why do you have your entire home directory in Source Control?

Comment: Judging from that screenshot it looks a bit like you initialized a git repository right in your home directory. That is almost certainly not a good idea. You should use a separate git repository for each of your projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you created a Git repository in your user home directory. This is almost certainly not what you want to do. To fix this, you need to first remove the repo with `rm -rf .git`. Then, create a directory for your project. For example, I usually create a `src` directory as the parent to all of my projects. When I start a new project, I do

```
mkdir src
cd src
git init new_project
```

This creates a single repo for the new project.

Comment: I'm sure that's it. And I have no idea how I did that. I saw that you can delete a repository with rm -rf .git. Is that the right thing to do here? I have no need to keep anything in that repo.

Comment: @Jstig Yes, that is exactly right. I updated my answer to include that info.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your help. (And thanks to all others who replied, as well.) Really appreciate it. On another note, when cd src gives    -bash: cd: src: No such file or directory. Is that normal?

Comment: @Jstig You need to create the `src` directory first. Or give it whatever name you wish. This is just a directory where you can keep all of your coding projects. `src` is a Linux convention. See my latest edit for how to create the directory from the command line.

Comment: @Jstig You can show your appreciation by accepting my answer when the site's timer allows you to.